# How to fix the looping forecast weather in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```
setForecast(unit: any, scaleTemp: any) {
    this.weatherService.getLocation().subscribe(data => {
      this.lat = JSON.parse(data['_body']).latitude;
      this.lon = JSON.parse(data['_body']).longitude;
      this.weatherService
        .sixDayForecast(this.lat, this.lon)
        .subscribe(res => {
          res.daily.data.shift();
          res.daily.data.pop();

          for (let i = 0; i < res.daily.data.length; i++) {
            const forecastWeather = new DailyForecast(
              res.daily.data[i].summary,
              res.daily.data[i].temperatureMax.toFixed(0) + scaleTemp,
              res.daily.data[i].time * 1000,
              res.daily.data[i].icon
            );
            this.dailyForecast.push(forecastWeather);
          }
          return this.dailyForecast;
        });
    });
  }
```

[image]

How to fix the looping in forecast weather.
What I want to do here is when I switch into celsius it should push instead it will replace into celsius

Comment: Does `setForecast` run when you toggle the toggle switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where You're flushing `this.dailyForecast` array.

So to avoid flickering (re-rendering) while You do `this.dailyForecast = [];` before calling service.

I recommend to get data, map it and immediately set to `this.dailyForecast`.

try this:

```
setForecast(unit: any, scaleTemp: any) {
  this.weatherService.getLocation().subscribe(data => {
    const body = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
    this.lat = body.latitude;
    this.lon = body.longitude;

    this
      .weatherService
      .sixDayForecast(this.lat, this.lon)
      .subscribe(res => {
        res.daily.data.shift();
        res.daily.data.pop();

        this.dailyForecast = res.daily.data.map(dailyData => 
          new DailyForecast(
            dailyData.summary,
            dailyData.temperatureMax.toFixed(0) + scaleTemp,
            dailyData.time * 1000,
            dailyData.icon
          )
        );
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: ```sixDayForecast(lat: string, lon: string) {
    return this.http.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/db9249f6adf5c8d4e27736cc9fa50e11/${lat},${lon}?units=si`).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }```